# Add a dynamic string variable to a curl script using Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I just began with Shell script (#!/bin/bash) language. And here is a script:

```
begin=$(date +"%s")
item='{
      "trigram" : "REII",
      "pickupReference" : "FRTEST01",
      "alertType" : "Overloaded",
      "alertStatus" : "Opened",
      "alertDetectionDate" : "2020-08-20",
      "properties": {"Property4": "13,00 %", "Property6": "45,58 %", "Property20": "35,00 %", "Property22": "18,00" }
    },'
for ((i=1;i<=3;i++)); do  
item+='
        {
          "trigram" : "REII",
          "pickupReference" : "FRTEST01",
          "alertType" : "Overloaded",
          "alertStatus" : "Opened",
          "alertDetectionDate" : "2020-08-20",
          "properties": {"Property4": "13,00 %", "Property6": "45,58 %", "Property20": "35,00 %", "Property22": "18,00" }
        },'
done
for ((i=1;i<=2;i++)); do   
    curl --location --request POST 'https://testurl.com/data' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer xxxx' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Cookie: BrowserId=XCVJyKw, ...' \
    --data-raw '[ '$item 
                    '{"trigram" : "REII",
                      "pickupReference" : "FRTEST01",
                      "alertType" : "Overloaded",
                      "alertStatus" : "Opened",
                      "alertDetectionDate" : "2020-08-20",
                      "properties": {"Property4": "13,00 %", "Property6": "45,58 %", "Property20": "35,00 %", "Property22": "18,00" }
                    }  ]'; 
    termin=$(date +"%s")
    difftimelps=$(($termin-$begin))
    
    if [ $i -eq 100 ] || [ $i -eq 500  ] || [ $i -eq 1000  ] || [ $i -eq 2000  ] || [ $i -eq 3000  ] || [ $i -eq 4000  ] || [ $i -eq 5000  ]; then
        echo "Alert $i - $(($difftimelps / 60)) minutes and $(($difftimelps % 60)) seconds elapsed for Script Execution.">> file_$i.txt
    fi
done

$SHELL
```

I want to add the variable `$item` to my bash script as shown above but It doesn't work, and I don't know why. Please help!

Comment: Are you trying to create an array, or just append to a single-string variable? c.f. Shellcheck.com

Comment: Append a single-string variable (the variable `$item`) in orther to use a list of item in the data-raw of my curl script. I've used `Shellcheck.com` but I didn't sort out. I'm very newbie with shell script. Thx.

Comment: Variables are only expanded inside double quotes, not inside single quotes.

Comment: I strongly recommend you use the `jq` utility to create JSON in shell scripts, rather than doing it by hand. It has methods to allow you to substitute variables into the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the `$item` quoting in that `curl` call.

```
curl ... \
     --data-raw '[ '"$item"'
                 {"trigram" : "REII",
                  "pickupReference" : "FRTEST01",
                  "alertType" : "Overloaded",
                  "alertStatus" : "Opened",
                  "alertDetectionDate" : "2020-08-20",
                  "properties": {"Property4": "13,00 %", "Property6": "45,58 %", "Property20": "35,00 %", "Property22": "18,00" }
                 }  ]';
```